# Initial assignment a Char Array using a Function in C

Tags: string, function, initialization, char, variable-assignment

as we know it in C, a string defining is,

```
char string[] = "Hello World";
```

That is OK,

But I want to use a function and at initial same up,
I tried those, For example;

```
char * to_string()
{
    return "Hello World";
}
```

Or;

```
char * to_String(void)    // Function
{
    char buff[16];
    sprintf(buff, "%s", "Hello World");
    return buff;
}

main()    // main function
{
   char Initial_String[] = to_String();
}
```

How to make this or any idea same another way.

I find what I dont send address of char Initial_String[] to fill into. No. is there Another method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you compile this, atleast in GCC, it will give you the following warning:
`b.c:9: warning: function returns address of local variable`
Why? Because `buff[]` is a local variable of function `to_string()`. Its scope is only inside the function `to_string()`. `main()` does not have any access to this variable. Try making `buff[]` a global variable instead.

Second problem: `char Initial_String[] = to_String();` cannot be assigned value in this way. `to_string()` returns a char pointer, hence assign the value thus:

```
char *Initial_String = to_String();
```

The code below will work:

```
char buff[16];
char* to_String(void)    // Function
{                      
            //char buff[16];   /*this is a local variable*/
            sprintf(buff, "%s", "Hello World");
            return buff;
}                      

int main(void)    // main function
{                      
           char *Initial_String = to_String();
           printf("%s", Initial_String);
           return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes You are right about local buffer mismake,

But This is not my wanting,

if I edit some differently,

```
char buff[16];
char* to_String(void)    // Function
{                      
            //char buff[16];   /*this is a local variable*/
            sprintf(buff, "%s", "Hello World");
            return buff;
}                      

int main(void)    // main function
{                      
           char *Initial_String_1 = to_String();
           char *Initial_String_2 = to_String();
           char *Initial_String_3 = to_String();

           printf("%s", Initial_String_1 );
           printf("%s", Initial_String_2 );
           printf("%s", Initial_String_3 );
```

in this case, all strings will be same, because They have same buffer address,

I want to open the topic little more.

```
struct
{
     long   aaa;
     short  bbb;
     int    ccc;
     char   ddd;
     .
     .
     .    // the list goes on
}elements;


typedef struct 
{
    int lengt;
    int *adress;
    char name[10];
}_list;

char* to_String(long variable)    // Function
{                      
            sprintf(buff, "%ld", variable);
            return buff;
}  

int main (void)
{
 _list My_List[] = {
                  { sizeof(elements.aaa), &elements.aaa , to_string( elements.aaa) },
                  { sizeof(elements.bbb), &elements.bbb , to_string( elements.bbb) },
                  { sizeof(elements.ccc), &elements.ccc , to_string( elements.ddd) }, 
                  .
                  .
                  . //// the list goes on
                 };
```

I do not know,  Do I make myself clear.
Here, string must be filled into name array, without assigning it the address.

I may have syntax mistake. the code is not tested with compiler. the idea is for illustrative purposes only.

I am trying to find a method for The purpose.

Thanks.